# C# web service method with a transaction commit return

Tags: c#, web-services, transactions

Is it possible to create a web service including a method that performs some operations and then expects a return value/action to commit those operations?

I need a method that returns some values. In the process of returning those values, some data needs to be inserted. After receiving those return values i need to make sure i am able to process them and then commit the initial method.

If the method doesn't receive the flag/commit/whatever, the inserts are rolled back.

Is this possible?
(Sorry if the wording is not clear, hope I'm understable)

I am doing this because i need to get a set of data, that is to slow to be returned with regular SQL. I am planning on zipping that (formatted) data  on the server (using a web service), and have the method return it to me in a zipped binary type. If something goes wrong in getting or processing that zipped binary, i need to be able to rollback the entire process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish a commit on web service end  after receiving web service response with single web service call is not possible, I am afraid. Http web services are stateless, you can make it stateful using sessions. You can make two services one for receiving response and other for performing commit. Between these two calls you can use session if they can help.

1. Call to receives set of values. You may set a session for next call timeout e.g. You should not start transaction in first call. Just return results. If your results are as per requirement of commit the save data with transaction. You can have some flag in DB records indicating the incomplete transaction in first call and commit or delete it second call and set flag accordingly.
2. Call for commit based on the first call result and put transaction over here for saving data.

Comment: Well it's possible then :)? If i never do No2, will the transaction hang indefinetly? What kind of transaction do i pick, start?

Comment: You should not start transaction in first call. Just return results. If your results are as per requirement of commit the save data with transaction.

Comment: That defeats the purpose, getting the data, and then uploading it back again. I could flag it as ok, but that's not the solution I am looking for.

Comment: You can have some flag in DB records indicating the incomplete transaction in first call and commit or delete it second call

Comment: This looks like the way to go. I don't even have to delete the data right away. The flag 'Ok', default false, should be enough. Accepting this unless somebody finds a way to use this concept in a transactional manner.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need two web services (if I understand your question correctly). The first one performs the action and returns a value. If the calling program verifies the return value it calls a second web service to perform the commit. Make sense?

Comment: Performing the commit means commiting a transaction? If so what kind of transaction do i pick, start? What transaction can be called from one session and committed in a second? I hope you mean **two web service methods**.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the solution should like this.

```
Method 1 - Create record and return the uid of it. Insert record in pending state
 Method 2 - Take parameter of created record and operation (approve or reject). Change the state of the record entered in method1.
```

Comment: Yes, i could go that route, with flagging the data. It's ok. But the question remains. The answer is i presume, no.